# JavaScript: ошибка при создании объекта из-за имени свойства

Tags: javascript

у меня такой вопрос по JavaScript:

Вот код класса User:

```
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }

  set name(value) {
    this.name = value + '!';
  }
}

let user = new User('Username');
console.log(user);
```

При попытке создания объекта new User('Username') происходит переполнение стека вызовов
(Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded) и объект не создается. Если изменить имя
переменной, в которую записывает значение сеттер, то все будет в порядке:

```
 // Так будет работать

  set name(value) {
    this._name = value + '!'; // this._name вместо this.name
  }
```

Вопрос в том, почему это не работало в начальном варианте.
Я приведу последовательность действий, поправьте меня там, где я ошибаюсь:

1. `let user = new User('Username');`   вызывается конструктор класса, создается пустой объект, на него теперь ссылается this.
2. `this.name = name;`  строка в конструкторе пытается записать свойство name, но т.к. это не простое свойство, а свойство-аксессор,
   то из прототипа создаваемого объекта this.**proto** вызывается сеттер.
3. `this.name = value + '!';`   на этой строке из сеттера отладчик в гугл-хром зацикливается. При этом видно,
   что к переменной value при каждой новой итерации добавляется еще один восклицательный знак (Username!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - до бесконечности).

Так что же все-таки происходит в пункте 3? Или ошибка закралась еще раньше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сетер вызывает сетер вызывает сетер ...

Гетер и сетер должны обращаться к полю, а не к свойству.

```js
class User {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value) {
    this._name = value + '!';
  }
}

let user = new User('Username');
console.log(user);
```

---

Представьте, что вместо `set name(value)` у Вас есть функция `setName`:

```
function setName(value) { 
  this.setName(value + "!"); 
}
```

Comment: А если чуть подробнее?
1. вызвался конструктор, он создал пустой объект, далее...
2. this.name он сам записать не может, т.к. в прототипе объекта есть сеттер
3. вызвался сеттер, который записал в this.name значение value ('Username')
4. выполнение вернулось в конструктор, который вернул объект с записанным свойством name
Что произошло между п.3 и п.4, что сеттер вызвал сеттер?

Comment: @bratislavka21 "выполнение вернулось в конструктор" - не вернулось.

Comment: @bratislavka21 В `name` не может ничего записаться. *Свойство* `name` - это два метода, они должны писать/читать что-то еще.

Comment: Ну да, не вернулось. Я просто хотел, чтобы поправили ход моих мыслей.
Igor, вот ты привел пример с функцией setName() вместо свойства-сеттера. Но ведь эта функция не вызовется автоматически при записи свойства, в отличие от сеттера, верно? А сеттер вызовется, и потом еще почему-то вызовет сам себя и т.д.

Comment: @bratislavka21 Метод `setName` - это то же самое, что сетер `set name`.

Comment: Igor, еще раз перечитал все, что ты писал. В общем, дошло. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @bratislavka21 Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.